# Fill/stretch the image to the right and bottom edges

Tags: css

I have this box with title + excerpt at the left and small thumbnail on the right. The problem is that the image is "floating" instead of go to the right and bottom borders. Here, the arrows are showing exactly the issue. Need to remove that white space there no matter how long is the excerpt text (usually same height but still).

[image]

here is example code that I have

```css
.large-9 {
    position: relative;
    width: 75%;
 }

.outter {
    border: 2px solid #707070 !important;
    height: 180px;
}
.columns {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0.9375em;
    padding-right: 0.9375em;
    float: left;   
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
        <div class="large-9 columns">                                                   
            <div class="name">                                  
                My title
            </div>
            <div class="excerpt">
                Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="columns">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"alt=""/>
        </div>
</div>
```

And here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/o3pL4ysj/)

Comment: This is an incorrect use of float: left seeing as you want it on the right but it comes after the text. Are you able to change the order of elements in the HTML? And do you want float at all? In particular is the text to flow under the image if the text is very long or are you really wanting two columns, text on the left, full height image on the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `float` because it is deprecated. Instead, use `flex` on the parent. Then set `flex: auto;` on columns and define a width for the image div. Then set the image's height and width to 100% and remove the padding set on that div previously.

```css
.large-9 {
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
}

.pad {
  border: 2px solid #707070 !important;
  height: 180px;
  display: flex;
}

.columns {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0.9375em;
  padding-right: 0.9375em;
  flex: auto;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


.pad > .columns:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="pad">
  <div class="large-9 columns">
    <div class="name">
      My title
    </div>
    <div class="excerpt">
      Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt Excerpt
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="columns">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use flex instead of float: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/